# Call procedure with return list hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I am calling a procedure that return a result of a select's.
I tested in MySQL and the procedure works fine.

```
Call timeline_procedure(1)
```

But when I call from hibernate I receive the error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!`

The code who call's the procedure is

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
            "Teste", properties);

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    List<Timeline> result = em
            .createQuery("Call timeline_procedure(:accountId)", Timeline.class)
            .setParameter("accountId", accountId)
            .getResultList();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use HQL, just try with SQL

```
List<Timeline> result = em
  .createSQLQuery("Call timeline_procedure(:accountId)")
  .addEntity(Timeline.class))
  .setParameter("accountId", accountId)
  .list();
```